# Scroll to top on route change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I use react.js 18.2.0 and react-router-dom v6.
the problem when I scroll down in the homepage then navigate to another page lets say terms and conditions. the expected behaviour when the page changes the window should be scrolled to top, but the current behaviour it still in the same level of scrollY.

I have tried every single solution like use ScrollToTop component or ScrollRestoration component,

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { MemoryRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material";
import { Home, Support, About, ContactUs, Terms, Calculator } from "./views";
import './styles/global.css';
import themes from "./utils/ThemeUtils";
import Layout from "./components/Layout";
import FullLayout from "./components/FullLayout";

function App() {
    const [theme, setTheme] = useState(localStorage.getItem("theme") || "light");
    const lightTheme = createTheme(themes.lightTheme);
    const darkTheme = createTheme(themes.darkTheme);

    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme === "light" ? lightTheme : darkTheme}>
            <Router >
                <Routes>
                    <Route element={<Layout setTheme={setTheme} theme={theme} />}>
                        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
                        <Route path="/terms" element={<Terms />} />
                        <Route path="/contact" element={<ContactUs />} />
                        <Route path="/support" element={<Support />} />
                    </Route>
                    <Route element={<FullLayout setTheme={setTheme} theme={theme} />}>
                        <Route path="/calculate" element={<Calculator />} />
                    </Route>
                </Routes>
            </Router>
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
}

export default App;
```

This is my App.js

Comment: Where have you tried using `ScrollRestoration`?

Comment: @Unmitigated under browser router, it says that you should use data router

Answer (score 0):

To use the `<ScrollRestoration>` component, you must use a data router. Here, you should use `createMemoryRouter` rather than `MemoryRouter`.

```
import { Route, createMemoryRouter, createRoutesFromElements, RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom';
const router = createMemoryRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <>
        <Route element={<Layout setTheme={setTheme} theme={theme} />}>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
            <Route path="/terms" element={<Terms />} />
            <Route path="/contact" element={<ContactUs />} />
            <Route path="/support" element={<Support />} />
        </Route>
        <Route element={<FullLayout setTheme={setTheme} theme={theme} />}>
            <Route path="/calculate" element={<Calculator />} />
        </Route>
    </>
  )
);
function App() {
    // ...
    return <ThemeProvider theme={theme === "light" ? lightTheme : darkTheme}>
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </ThemeProvider>;
}
```